# JBoss authentication issue

Tags: jboss, jboss6.x

I am newbie to JBoss and I have the application running in JBoss 6.2.
We usually have the login set up using JSF. It's showing a screen with username and password (created by JSF) and that's an internal part of the application and that works fine.

But I came to know there is basic authentication setup available in JBoss. We can configure it in a way that it requires to pass through authentication. 
I searched on the internet and I found a way to introduce it like below:

```
D:\workspace_Csmart\jboss-eap-6.2\bin>add-user
What type of user do you wish to add?
 a) Management User (mgmt-users.properties)
 b) Application User (application-users.properties)
(a): b
Enter the details of the new user to add.
Using realm 'ApplicationRealm' as discovered from the existing property files.

Username : prabhu
User 'prabhu' already exits, would you like to update the existing user password and roles
Is this correct yes/no? yes
Password :
Re-enter Password :

What groups do you want this user to belong to? (Please enter a comma separated list, or leave blank for none)[user]: prabhu
Updated user 'prabhu' to file 'D:\workspace_Csmart\jboss-eap-
6.2\standalone\configuration\application-users.properties'
Updated user 'prabhu' to file 'D:\workspace_Csmart\jboss-eap-6.2\domain\configuration\application-users.properties'
Updated user 'prabhu' with groups prabhu to file 'D:\workspace_Csmart\jboss-eap-6.2\standalone\configuration\application-roles.prope
Updated user 'prabhu' with groups prabhu to file 'D:\workspace_Csmart\jboss-eap-6.2\domain\configuration\application-roles.propertie
Is this new user going to be used for one AS process to connect to another AS process?
e.g. for a slave host controller connecting to the master or for a Remoting connection for server to server EJB calls.
yes/no? yes
To represent the user add the following to the server-identities definition <secret value="cHJhYmh1QDEyMw==" />
```

And you see the user and password is updated in properties, so I ran the server with my local setup and it's up and running. But I didn't see any popup asking JBoss basic credentials. It's just directly going to the login page: `http://10.17.195.15:8080/Proj/home.xhtml`

Do I have to do anything with `standalone.xml`? `security` tag?

I would really appreciate it if anyone can point out what I am missing here? What do I need to do to make it work for JBoss Basic Authentication? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. This somehow helped me to solve this I just did following things:

Under WebContent folder:

### step1: change in web.xml

```
<security-constraint>

        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>All resources</web-resource-name>
            <description>Protects all resources</description>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>

        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>prabhu</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>

    <security-role>
        <role-name>prabhu</role-name>
    </security-role>

    <login-config>
        <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
        <realm-name></realm-name>
    </login-config>
```

### step2 : change in jboss-web.xml

```
<jboss-web>
    <context-root>C-SMART</context-root>
    <security-domain>java:/jaas/other</security-domain>
 </jboss-web>
```

### step 3 : creating user and password for jboss basic authentication

D:\workspace_Csmart\jboss-eap-6.2\bin>add-user

```
What type of user do you wish to add?
 a) Management User (mgmt-users.properties)
 b) Application User (application-users.properties)
(a): b

Enter the details of the new user to add.
Using realm 'ApplicationRealm' as discovered from the existing property files.
Username : prabhu
User 'prabhu' already exits, would you like to update the existing user password and roles
Is this correct yes/no? yes
Password :
Re-enter Password :
What groups do you want this user to belong to? (Please enter a comma separated list, or leave blank for none)[prabhu]: prabhu
Updated user 'prabhu' to file 'D:\workspace_Csmart\jboss-eap-6.2\standalone\configuration\application-users.properties'
Updated user 'prabhu' to file 'D:\workspace_Csmart\jboss-eap-6.2\domain\configuration\application-users.properties'
Updated user 'prabhu' with groups prabhu to file 'D:\workspace_Csmart\jboss-eap-6.2\standalone\configuration\application-roles.properties'
Updated user 'prabhu' with groups prabhu to file 'D:\workspace_Csmart\jboss-eap-6.2\domain\configuration\application-roles.properties'
Is this new user going to be used for one AS process to connect to another AS process?
e.g. for a slave host controller connecting to the master or for a Remoting connection for server to server EJB calls.
yes/no? yes
To represent the user add the following to the server-identities definition <secret value="cHJhYmh1QDEyMw==" />
Press any key to continue . . .
```

### Step 4: verified above user changes reflected in following files

'D:\workspace_Csmart\jboss-eap-6.2\standalone\configuration\application-users.properties'
'D:\workspace_Csmart\jboss-eap-6.2\domain\configuration\application-users.properties'
'D:\workspace_Csmart\jboss-eap-6.2\standalone\configuration\application-roles.properties'
'D:\workspace_Csmart\jboss-eap-6.2\domain\configuration\application-roles.properties'

And its worked fine for me.. Thanks all your help..

Answer (score 3):

**1)** First you need to move all your `jsf` files (that need protection) in some folder, for example `secured` folder.

**2)** Create `index.jsf` that redirects to protected start page and place it outside `secured` folder.

**3)** Create `logout.jsf` which does `session.invalidate()` and redirects to `index.jsf` page.

```
<html>
<body>
<%
        if(session!=null)
         {
               session.invalidate();%>
              <jsp:forward page="index.jsp" />
  <%                  
                } else{
  %>
           Logged Out Successfully....
 <% }%>
</body>
</html>
```

**4)** Add security constraints to `web.xml`.

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>MySecureResources</web-resource-name>
        <description>Some Description</description>
        <url-pattern>/secured/*</url-pattern>
        <http-method>GET</http-method>
        <http-method>POST</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>TestRole</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
</login-config>
<security-role>
    <role-name>TestRole</role-name>
</security-role>
```

**5)** Create `jboss-web.xml` file inside projects `WEB_INF` folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE jboss-web PUBLIC
    "-//JBoss//DTD Web Application 5.0//EN"
    "http://www.jboss.org/j2ee/dtd/jboss-web_5_0.dtd">
<jboss-web>
 <security-domain>java:/jaas/BasicAuthWebAppPolicy</security-domain>
 <context-root>/basicSecurityWebApp</context-root>
</jboss-web>
```

**6)** Create a file with some name like `basicSecurityWebApp-roles.properties.` and place it in `WEB_INF/classes` folder. Define role there and assign that role to some user.

```
TestUserOne=TestRole
```

**7)** Create another file with some name like `basicSecurityWebApp-users.properties` and place it in `WEB-INF/classes` folder and define username and password.

```
TestUserOne=TestPassword
```

**8)** Now you should modify `login-config.xml` in `$PROFILE/conf/` folder. Add application-policy with the same name as `BasicSecurityWebApp`.

```
<application-policy name="BasicAuthWebAppPolicy">
 <authentication>
   <login-module code="org.jboss.security.auth.spi.UsersRolesLoginModule"       flag="required">
     <module-option name="usersProperties">basicSecurityWebApp-users.properties</module-option>
     <module-option name="rolesProperties">basicSecurityWebApp-roles.properties</module-option>
   </login-module>
 </authentication>
```

**9)** Deploy application to JBoss.

**10)** Now every time you have to access our website you have to enter user and password you provided in credentials file (username as “TestUserOne” and password as “TestPassword”).

---

For more details see [This](http://middlewaremagic.com/jboss/?p=220)